# Why is realloc() introducing some random values into a dynamic array when called multiple times?

Tags: c, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation, realloc

I am trying to fill a dynamically generated array using a for loop and make it bigger whenever needed using realloc(). However, when realloc is called several times on the memory, it replaces some values, especially the first and last few with seemingly random numbers.

This is the code I tested the said with:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void fill(int * array, int size, int number_of_values) {
    for (int i = 0; i < number_of_values; i++) {
        if (i == size) {
            size *= 2;
            array = realloc(array, sizeof(int) * size);
        }

        array[i] = 100;
    }
}

int main() {
    int *array;
    int number_of_values = 21;
    int size = 5;

    array = malloc(sizeof(int) * size);

    fill(array, size, number_of_values);

    for (int i = 0; i < number_of_values; i++) {
        printf("%i ", array[i]);
    }
}
```

I tried reimplementing the code several times and looked at the array directly after assigning `100` to it, but all the values are assigned correctly at first and then change somehow. I also observed, that said behavior only seems to happen when there are more than 20 items assigned to the array in the loop.

The output of the program normally looks something like this:

```
10425976 10436440 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 134217736
```

Whereas when I set `number_of_values` to 20 and therefore only assign 20 values, the output looks like the following:

```
100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100
```

I also looked through some references of the `realloc` function, but as far as I'm concerned, I used it correctly.

Comment: You discard the pointer returned by `realloc`. (You change `fill`'s `array`, but not `main`'s.) You are using a pointer that's no longer valid.

Comment: Your print loop prints values from the array created by the very first call to malloc, not by realloc.

Comment: `array = realloc(array,...)` is a memory leak  in case the `realloc` fails. You should always assign the return value of `realloc` to another pointer to check it.

Comment: @ikegami Doesn't `array = realloc(array, sizeof(int) * size);` set `array` to the new pointer?

Comment: Yes, that changes `fill`'s `array`. Not `main`'s, though. There are two variables named `array`, and you are only changing one of them.

Comment: @Stephan, it does but only in `fill`. `main` still has the old pointer.

Comment: Thank you, returning the pointer helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your function must return the newly allocated array.

```
int* fill(int * array, int size, int number_of_values) {
    ...
    return array;
}

int main() {
    ...
    array = fill(array, size, number_of_values);
    ,,,
}
```

Beginners generally get this wrong for a couple of reasons. They might think that because the two variables called `array` in `main` and in `find` both have the same name they are the same variable. This is not true.

The other reason is that sometimes beginners think that there is something special about pointers. If you change a pointer inside a function somehow it also changes the corresponding pointer in the calling function. I think this is a misunderstanding based on the fact that you can use a pointer to change the value *being pointed at*, but the pointer itself has the same rules as any other type of variable.

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I thought. Several other people who are also learning C had the same issue.

Comment: @Vntto Which one did you think, the first one or the second one?

Comment: The second one, I didn't realize, that I am not changing the being pointed at, but the pointer itself

Comment: @Vntto Yes, it's a common misunderstanding.